# Error while trying to upgrade to higher android version

Tags: windows, upgrade, android

I am getting an error trying to update my android packages.

[image]

It is saying momentarily deactivate your antivirus software.
 --*I am not using any anti virus softwares*.

Please close any programs that may be accessing the directory.--*I haven't kept the directory folder open.The only program that might be accessing it might be my adb in eclipse.*

I am currently using android 2.3.

Can you tell me what is the problem here.How can i resolve this

Comment: Since this question is related to a problem on the PC when having the Android connected, this question is within scope for Super User.

Comment: Have you tried to find out if anything else is locking the folder? [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) might help you with that.

Comment: "I am not using any anti virus softwares"

That scares me.

Comment: @Nifle :It worked like a charm.Thanks a lot.Can u post this as the answer so that i can accept it and upvote you.

Comment: @rogerstone - Done

Comment: @Nifle -Cannot upvote you as i need 15 rep :(.Will do it when i get it.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to find out if anything else is locking the folder? [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) might help you with that.